# Slice off and store prefix of string in-place

Tags: javascript

In my former life, I worked with a couple of languages that used to have a string "slice" option where I could literally "slice" out part of the string and save the sliced out part into another variable.

In JS for example, I want to be able to remove the first 2 positions from a string and store that value into another variable.

It would appear in JS that to accomplish the same thing requires two steps.

```
var twoDigits = myString.slice(0, 2);
myString = myString.substring(2);
```

Is there a better way to do this without resorting to writing my own function?

Comment: Probably not. Writing a function is probably not even worth the effort; it’d have to have multiple return values, and that’s a pain if you’re not on ES6. This is one of those things about immutable strings…